# Screen media queries overriding print rules (in Chrome)

Tags: css, printing, media-queries

Have a look at the following CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwYYBN (I removed non-relevant parts of the code).

At the top of the CSS is a couple media queries for resizing the slides (these are auto generated by Less). Here's an example of one:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 430px) {
  .slides .slide {
    width: calc( 100% / 1);
  }
}
```

Then, a little further on, is a print media query which is supposed to override it, because I always want the size of the slides to be 50% on a print:

```
@media print {
  .slides .slide {
    width: calc( 100% / 2);
    color: gold;
  }
}
```

The problem is the width in this print query is completely ignored; when printing it always uses the width defined by the currently active `screen` rule! You can test this by issuing a print the CodePen with different screen sizes.

The `@media` rule should work as far as I can see; the rule is matched `print`, and it also appears later in the CSS. I know it is active, because the items do change color to `gold`. But the width doesn't change. I've even tried making it more specific (by pointing it to `body .slides .slide` and adding a `min-width` to the query) to no avail. Even `!important` does not work.

Can anyone tell me what is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem was caused by a transition:

```
.slides .slide {
  -webkit-transition: width 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.65, 0.52, 0.97);
  transition: width 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.65, 0.52, 0.97);
}
```

The change in width actually triggered this transition, which frozen at the moment of generating the print view. After removing the transition, everything is working well.

This transition should not run however, as it's inside a `print` media query. I've submitted [a bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=&id=580117#makechanges) to Chromium for this and they acknowledged the issue.

Comment: Having the same problem in 2022 on Chrome. Having a widget on the page that is hidden under the right edge of the screen and appears on a user action. Then on screens smaller than 992px it goes under the bottom edge of the screen. The element has transition on it, so when printing this page, the widget is moving for a second to the bottom and then reposition himself back to the right. 
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t10x6eLv/
Video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VMqht4VImsJngQhpUGnalHx13IowQRY3/view?usp=sharing